# Remove navigation collection entity from EFCore lazy loaded context - navigation collection not updated immediately

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

For legacy reason we use an injected lazy loader in EF Core.

In the code below `Context.Add(child)` results in the lazy loaded navigation collection being updated but `Context.Remove(child)` does not. `SaveChanges()` must be called first. Is this by design?

Now I know I can call `Parent.Children.Remove(child)` and that is hunky dory but our solution requires invoking `Context.Remove(child)`. I don't like just chucking in `SaveChanges()` without understanding why it is necessary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace EFDemo
{
    public class Parent
    {
        private Action<object, string> _lazyLoader;
        public Parent() { }

        public Parent(Action<object, string> lazyLoader)
        {
            _lazyLoader = lazyLoader;
        }
        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        private List<Child> _children;
        
        public List<Child> Children {
            get
            {
                _lazyLoader?.Invoke(this, "Children");
                _children ??= new List<Child>();
                return _children;
            } 
            set => _children = value; 
        }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class EFDemoContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }
        
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var connectionString =
                "Server=tcp:localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=EFDemo;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxx@xxxx;Encrypt=False;Max Pool Size=500;Pooling=True;";
            
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
                .EnableDetailedErrors()
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var context = new EFDemoContext();
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.Migrate();

            var p = new Parent()
            {
                Name = "Alice",
                Children = new List<Child>
                {
                    new() { Name = "Bob" },
                    new() { Name = "Charlie" },
                    new() { Name = "Doris" },
                }
            };
            context.Add(p);
            context.SaveChanges();

            Debug.Assert(p.Children.Count == 3, "Initial children not found");
            context.Add(new Child() { Name = "Elizabeth", Parent = p });
            Debug.Assert(p.Children.Count == 4, "New child not found");
            context.Remove(p.Children.First());
            //context.SaveChanges(); // we need to save in order to succeed
            Debug.Assert(p.Children.Count == 3, "Child not removed");
        }
    }
}
```

--- Followup --

This [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10114) addresses the matter precisely. There is some inconsistency I think in how fix up occurs for deletes but clearly an internal EFCore fix for this broke too many things.

Comment: `DbContext.Add`, `DbContext.Remove`, `DbContext.Attach` etc. just change the state of the entity. You still need to call `DbContext.SaveChanges` at the end to make changes in DB. `context.Remove(p.Children.First())` only marked the entity for removal which will happen when you call `SaveChanges`. All of your assertions would fail if you don't save changes after `context.Add(p)`, but reset the context (for example) with `context.ChangeTracker.Clear()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I know the facts that you relate but to me it seems very inconsistent that `Context.Add()` will; update the lazy loaded collection before save changes but that `Context.Remove()` does not.

Comment: It's not `Context.Add` the one making the change, but the EF Core which does the relationship fixup. You specified parent with `Parent = p` when creating a child, EF Core detected that parent already exists in context and updated the `Children` relationship. `Context.Remove` only marks the entity for deletion, nothing else. What you could try is detaching the child and checking what happens (I don't know off the top of my head). I'm not sure whether EF Core would perform some changes on a collection in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This EF Core behavior is unrelated to lazy loading and is caused by the so called *navigation fixup* performed by many operations of the context change tracker.

While it might seem inconsistent with `Add`, in fact both them (as well as other change tracking related operations) are trying to ensure the following invariants for **tracked** entities:

1. Tracked `Parent parent`: For each tracked `Child child` in `parent.Children`, then `child.Parent == parent`
2. Tracked `Child child`: If `child.Parent != null`, then `child.Parent.Childen.Contains(child)`

When you call `Add` (or `Attach`, `Update`) of `Child child` with `child.Parent != null`, because of the invariant #2 EF Core adds it to the `parent.Children` collection if it is not already there.

However, when you call `Remove` with `Child child` having `child.Parent != null)`, the entity is marked for deletion (`State = EntityState.Deleted`), but the `Parent` property is not nulled out, hence due to the aforementioned rules it cannot be removed from `child.Parent.Children` collection. And not only that, in fact it will be added to that collection if it is not there, which can be seen with code like this

```cs
var child = new Child { Id = 1, Parent = new Parent { Id = 1 } };
Debug.Assert(child.Parent.Children.Count == 0);
context.Remove(child);
Debug.Assert(child.Parent != null && child.Parent.Children.Contains(child));
```

Now the question might be why the `Parent` is not nulled out. I guess because `Deleted` state is considered temporary (you might decide later to set it to something else, thus "undeleting" the "deleted" entity).

So what they do is wait you to "confirm" the entity state/operation, which happens after `SaveChanges`, and more specifically by the `ChangeTracker.AcceptAllChanges()` call after successfully applying the modifications in database. This call converts the `Deleted` temporary state to `Detached` persistent state. Since `Detached` means the entity will no more be tracked, they perform the final navigation fixup, which in this case is removing the child from the parent collection and nulling out the parent.

---

The above explains the rationale behind the `Remove` behavior. What if you don't like it and want child to be removed from the parent collection immediately. One way is to replace the EF Core service responsible for that with your own - in this case, `INavigationFixer` interface with default implementation in `NavigationFixer` class, but both are undocumented and considered part of the "internal API" (even though they are public from C# POV) - this is not a problem for me, but for many people it is. So another option is to hook into context change tracking events and perform the desired action. For instance, add the following to your derived context class

```cs
void Initialize()
{
    ChangeTracker.Tracked += OnEntityTracked;
    ChangeTracker.StateChanged += OnEntityStateChanged;
}

void OnEntityStateChanged(object sender, EntityStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewState == EntityState.Deleted)
        OnEntityDeleted(e.Entry);
}

void OnEntityTracked(object sender, EntityTrackedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.FromQuery && e.Entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
        OnEntityDeleted(e.Entry);
}

void OnEntityDeleted(EntityEntry entry)
{
    foreach (var refEntry in entry.References)
    {
        var refEntity = refEntry.CurrentValue;
        if (refEntity != null)
        {
            var inverseNavigation = refEntry.Metadata.Inverse;
            if (inverseNavigation != null && inverseNavigation.IsCollection)
            {
                var collection = inverseNavigation.GetCollectionAccessor();
                collection.Remove(refEntity, entry.Entity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and call `Initialize` from constructor(s).

Comment: Great answer Ivan. I got side tracked by our use of the lazy loader. Thanks very much for your time and opinion.